# Search , Filter by SlugRelatedField in view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with **searching** , **filtering** by SlugRelatedFiled which I get it in Serializers in **Django Rest Framework** .I just want to filter , search by category names of products.

Here is my serializers.

```
class CosmeticCategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CosmeticCategory
        fields = ["url", "pk", "name", "description"]

class CosmeticDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=CosmeticCategory.objects.filter(), slug_field="name",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Cosmetic
        #read_only_fields = ["date_added", "date_updated"]
        fields = [
            "image_url",
            "url",
            "pk",
            "name",
            "category",
            "price",
            "description",
            "color",
            "volume",
            "skin_type",
            "target_area"
        ]
```

Views.

```
class CosmeticList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Cosmetic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CosmeticSerializer
    name = "cosmetic-list"
    # filter_class = CosmeticFilter
    filter_bakcends = (SearchFilter,OrderingFilter)
    filter_fields = ["category","brand","name"]#-----
    ordering_fields = ["name", "price","volume","brand"]
    search_fields = ["name","brand","category"]#------
    #permission_classes = [IsAdminUserOrReadOnly]
```

Models.

```
class CosmeticCategory(models.Model):
    """Categories for cosmetic products"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]


class Cosmetic(models.Model):
    #Id = models.IntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=3)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        CosmeticCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cosmetics"
    )
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
    skin_type = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
    target_area = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name + " " + self.brand)
```

**Output for search:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 199, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 38, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 150, in filter_queryset
    queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/filters.py", line 122, in filter_queryset
    queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.and_, conditions))
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1373, in _add_q
    check_filterable,
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1381, in _add_q
    check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1311, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/Users/sundetmukhtar/Desktop/SoftwareProject/Test2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1156, in build_lookup
    raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

or it **istartswith**(if you set search_fields = ["^category"....])

**Output for filtering:**.

```
 "category": [
        "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."
    ]
```

It does not matter if set DjangoFilterBackend(

```
filter_bakcends = (SearchFilter,OrderingFilter,DjangoFilterBackend)
filterset_fields = ["category"]
```

or use default filter.

```
 filter_fields = ["brand","name","category"]
```

)
**URL:**
https://127.0.0.1:8000/cosmetics

```
path("cosmetics/", views.CosmeticList.as_view(), name=views.CosmeticList.name)
```

I think I have to set **icontains** or **iexact** value but I don't know how to do it.
I found some related questions how to set these values but they are a little bit different.

Comment: Can you show the complete code like your models and what the url is which is giving this error and a complete stack trace Would help a lot debugging this.

Comment: Done.I have added models  and changed output for filtering.

Comment: Like I mentioned above...what's the url you are hitting in the browser that's giving you error. The operation is being done on Category model which you haven't provided. Please do provide these also. The URL you are hitting is the one that's generating error so it's needed to debug.

Comment: I added it.The Category model is a CosmeticCategory model.

Comment: What I meant by url was the url you are putting in your browser or postman or whatever other app you are using for you api testing.